# amsmath: how can I number individual equations in a gathered environment?

Tags: numbering, amsmath

I have a complex set of equations, displayed using amsmath's `align` and `gathered` environments. I need to refer to some of the cases in the `gathered` environments, but they are not numbered. Here is a MWE (edited to be closer to the full example):

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  foo &= \left\{
           \begin{gathered}
             one \label{one} \\
             two % \label{two}
           \end{gathered}
         \right\} \\
  bar &= something similar 
\end{align}

There is \eqref{one} and \eqref{two}.

\end{document}
```

If I uncomment the second label, I have an error because of multiple labels.

Is it possible to number these sub equations?

Comment: Why do you need the align? The -ed does not provide eqn numbers so you'll need a different approach

Comment: I suppose putting foo= on both of them, or foo&= and &= isn't pretty enough.

Comment: I need the align because I have several of such lines.

Answer (score 2):

this looks like a job for `empheq`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left={foo = \empheqlbrace},right={\empheqrbrace}]{align}
 &one \label{one}\\
 &two \label{two}
\end{empheq}

With cross references to equations \eqref{one} and \eqref{two}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `empheq` looks great but it does not seem to work inside an align: I need several similar equations aligned at the equal sign.

Comment: @brab -- fair enough.  i'll keep looking; this is a reasonable question, so a "reasonable" solution would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a kludge, but it works.  With the right brace in there it really is just one equation.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{4in}
\begin{align}
  & one \label{one} \\
foo = \smash{\left\lbrace \rule{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip} \right.}
 & \phantom{two}
 \smash{\left. \rule{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip} \right\rbrace} \notag\\
  & two \label{two}
\end{align}

There is \eqref{one} and \eqref{two}.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]